# How to remove the outline of Entry control in Maui iOS?

Tags: ios, maui

How can I remove the outline from the Entry control in Maui on iOS?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample of you current entry control?

Comment: 1) Requires writing a custom handler. I see some videos: [`maui entry ios remove border`](https://www.google.com/search?q=maui+entry+ios+remove+border). 2) FYI: While it doesn't help you now, refer in future to [Entry and Editor: option to disable border and underline](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7906), to see if any progress is made in making this a standard option, or if anyone suggests a workaround.

Comment: I see videos that supposedly show what you need to do. I haven't looked at them, have you?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Turns out YouTube was the friend I needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this method in the App constructor (before you set MainPage)

```
    private void SetUpEntry()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("SetUpEntry", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID

#elif IOS || MACCATALYST

            //remove outline
            handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;

#elif WINDOWS
      
#endif
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change AppDelegate class from:

```
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
```

to:

```
 protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
 {
     Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("SetUpEntry", (handler, view) =>
     {
         handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
     });

    return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
 }
```